# Refreshing the page of a suggested edit audit kills the audit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

### Steps to repro:

1. Find a suggested edit that seems suspicious *(clearly an audit)*
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> OR the refresh button *(who uses the GUI anyway)*
3. ...
4. Break the audit! (see image)

<strike>[Link to the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1889548)</strike> (*Looks like audits are re-used and the link is not longer valid.*)

> [image]

When you get a suggested edit that is an audit and accidentally refresh the page, instead of just showing the normal page with all four buttons it changes to this layout with a "item is not reviewable". I've reproduced it many times.

*The normal behavior is exactly similar to the picture on the left below. The audit is not supposed to have "community" as its username AND should show the 4 buttons.*

It's a way to avoid audits, and is pretty annoying!

---

**EDIT before even submitting the post!** *pretty sure it's the fastest edit to ever happen on SO*.

Repro'd Again! *(and again, can be repro'd anytime)*

> **Correct behavior** *(When you stumble for the first time on the edit.)*
>   [image]
>
> **Bad behavior** *(When you've refreshed the page.)*
>   [image: imagr]

Comment: If anybody can try on other browsers, I'm at 20 review already...

Comment: Easier way to know it's an audit: it's suggested by Community user. No valid edit can be suggested like that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd At the first screen (where you have four buttons) it is not suggested by community. Then when you refresh community appears with the next button only.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Guess I didn't hit audit for too long! :/

Comment: May I ask: Who cares? If you can tell its an audit, why bother?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Because it breaks. It is not supposed to get in the form "not reviewable anymore". I don't care it's an audit or not. The fact is that when you press F5 it breaks it in that case.

Comment: Seems it havent been solved yet, I always keep my browser on auto-reload for every 6 sec.. *AND*.. LUCKY ME ***I can never fail suggested-edit audit***  :P

Comment: Voted it up. I don't even know a refresh counts as ***passed*** or ***failed***

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica Neither, as you never reviewed/voted on the audit. It just makes you ineligible to vote on the audit.