# Suggested edit by the Community user must be removed from review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, community-user

There are many posts related to why the Community user rejected or edited a post but my problem is bit different.

My problem is that, **a suggested edit proposed by The Community user should not be in review queue altogether as the reviewer cannot review**(Maybe because he has moderator rights..)

Please find the image below.

> [image: ...]

As you can see there is no Approve, Reject or Improve option , then why is it in review queue? The related [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2468458)
The reviewer hardly or never looks at who is OP or who has suggested the edit, but first goes to review content. After reviewing, i.e. (wasting) his time he finds its unreviewable, which is really annoying. Moreover Community edited post comes very often. In my case it happened *3 consecutive suggested edits in a row*. In the image posted above, I would REJECT the edit or may be IMPROVE, because it adds some non-related edits to a post, But I cant..

***In short,***

My questions/suggestion:-

1. Suggested edits by Community user be removed from Suggested edit
   queue.
2. Who can approve or reject such edits.

Comment: Suggested edit from Community user means it is suggested by anonymous user.

Comment: Agreed, he is anonymous user or maybe deleted user, But its not review-able, being in review queue is a waste of time for the one who reviews it..

Comment: It's not wasting of time. Do you know anything about [Review-audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audits)?

Comment: yes,`Test items in review queues that are designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users that don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing.` but are you saying the above mentioned Edit is a genuine edit and no improvement needed?? I would certainly Reject the suggested EDIT.. Just check the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2468458)

Comment: That's why I am saying it looks like Review-audit.

Comment: In that review page it is mentioned : **Review audit passed 25 mins ago**

Comment: Hmm, its review-audit??, then what is he testing `MY PATIENCE`.. :( The problem is, it pops up quite often. After reviewing the question I realize I just wasted my time, and as I mentioned 3 consecutive suggested edits in an row... and not so worthy edit..

Comment: In review-audit we are suppose to be attentive, but here, we do nothing...

Comment: @hims056 No, the review page didn't mentioned review was passed when it poped up, I will update the image if u want

Comment: How did you reach that suggested edit? It looks like you stumbled into review audit assigned to a different user while he still did not review it.

Comment: Just ran into the same situation `This item is not reviewable.`. Rather annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2468458) you are talking about is [review-audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audits). Which are added to the queue deliberately to check whether reviewers review it properly or not. The main aim of such review audits is to prevent [review abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-abuse) by robo-reviewers. If they fail some reviews the get [review suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-suspension). So this is not wasting of time but a method to make review system more effective<sup>(I am not getting better word)</sup>.

---

**Edit:**

As per testing by [@Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187940/suggested-edit-by-the-community-user-must-be-removed-from-review-queue/187947?noredirect=1#comment-578356)

When two users get the same review audit, the second one get the message "This item is not reviewable". After the first reviewer review it (regardless of fail or pass) other users get the message like:

> Review audit passed(or fail) XX mins ago:
>    reviewed this XX mins ago: Reject/Approve/etc...

Comment: If it really is an audit, shouldn't it give `Congrats, you passed` or `Sorry you failed`?? type of messages...

Comment: @CRUSADER - such type of message is shown only to the reviewer only one time (after reviewing).

Comment: I am sorry, may be I misunderstood, but, I never saw `congrats or Sorry` messages in suggested edit queue. But I saw multiple suggested edits by Community user..

Comment: @CRUSADER - Suggested edit by the Community user doesn't mean it is a review audit.

Comment: I had just NEXT button at my disposal, how would I ever know that its audit or genuine edit. I cannot review those items even if it was genuine even if I am >2K user..

Comment: @hims056 let's check my theory. Please go to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2469015). What do you see?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - `This item is not reviewable.` and `Next` button. (Same as image given by the OP)

Comment: @hims056 and now? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - You are genius: I got it: `Review audit passed 14 secs ago:
Shadow Wizard reviewed this 14 secs ago: Reject`

Comment: To sum this up: it's a rare race condition where two users got the same review audit; the second get "This item is not reviewable" until the first reject (or approve) it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yup. Editing...

Comment: @CRUSADER - See the edit now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you for the insight, I guess this is something unavoidable, In my case it happened thrice in a row, well, may be my hard Luck...

Comment: @CRUSADER cheers, weird indeed let us know if it happens again. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  :)  accepting the answer for now....

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd What you know, got this situation again .. 3 in a row,,.  Well, I think I got this time though, it was [like in here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175911/221351). I have kept my browser on auto-refresh for every  6sec. So I get this.. Lucky me I ***can never fail the suggested audit then***. :P

Comment: @CRUSADER Guess the devs never expected the user to keep refreshing the page. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd :( Too bad indeed, I think there are many like me how keep page refreshing especially in review sessions..