# I think I just broke Review Audits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

So, I was reviewing Suggested Edits on StackOverflow. I made a determination on one edit, and the next appeared. I immediately thought "wait--I wonder" and clicked my browser's back button to check something else regarding that review. I honestly don't remember what it was, but everything turned out fine. So I clicked the forward button on my browser to get back to the next suggested edit in line. And I got this:

[image]

This suggested edit is pretty clearly a review audit, and if you'll glance at the text inside the shiny red circle, you'll see that reloading the audit in the browser window generates the error:

> This item is not reviewable.

When I proceeded onward to the next edit, I was not given another audit. Edits proceeded as normal.

The problem I see here is that it gives robo-reviewers a way to cheat the audit system. It would take them a little extra time, but it would be a 100% guarantee that they would never fail an audit. It's easy: load next review, click backspace key, load review again. If you see the error, hit next and repeat. If you don't, press approve and repeat.

So... Fix? :)

**Update**:

Huh... Further interesting is this. I still had the tab open, and I refreshed the page (I don't know why, I think some part of my brain was expecting a new review to appear, which of course didn't happen.) But upon refresh, I saw this:

[image]

That's right--someone else got my audit, and it tells me if they passed or failed it! Curiouser and curiouser.

Also, here's a [link to the audit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2814892), in case that helps anybody.

Comment: Or, they could... you know, actually review the post. That would be faster than all these back-forward shenanigans.

Comment: @Doorknob They could, but if they did then they wouldn't be a problem :) Maybe you're right and no one would do this. But I just realized it's a pretty obvious cue that it's an audit (not that suggested edit audits aren't pretty obvious to begin with...) so I just figured I'd mention it!

Comment: You can see others' audits anyway when you have a link to them like you did (or in the history tab once you get 10k)

Comment: What's a smarty template?

Comment: AFAIK, if you browse away from an audit, someone else can "claim" it; and as only one user can process an audit at one time, you get `This item is not reviewable`.

Comment: Just happened to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

You get in to this situation when you **refresh or accidently refresh** the review screen and it turn out to be an audit. Already reported this [situation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187940/221351). The same was discussed highly [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175911/221351). Although it still remains unFixed.. I Guess the developers never expected the user to keep refreshing the page..